# How to copy all header files only from various directory to other location with the same directory structure using CMake?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on Android NDK project where i need to using an existing cpp library.
So i need to generate '.so' file and i need to extract all the headers(.h/.hpp) file to other location so that i can integrate this with Android app.
My try

```
 add_custom_command(TARGET cpp_parser-lib POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
                    copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/cpp_example/libxml/xmlparser/*.h"
                    "${distribution_DIR}/include/cpp_example/libxml/xmlparser/"

                    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
                    copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/cpp_example/libxml/*.h"
                    "${distribution_DIR}/include/cpp_example/libxml/"

"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/cpp_example/parser/proto/protobuf/*.h"
                    "${distribution_DIR}/include/cpp_example/parser/proto/protobuf/"

.
.
.
)
```

It works. But in this case  all the destination directory must be present already.

My Summary is

**How to extract all the files with given extension only with directory path to another location ?**
[image: Left is Actual input and right should be output]

Comment: I do not know why people do vote down with the question.
Need any explanation. please comment

Comment: "But in this case all the destination directory must be present already." - So the problem in creating a directory? Just add `COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E make_directory <...>` before the command which copies files.

Comment: ok . let me try this

Comment: Good edit: Now the picture fits to the screen (at least on PC).

Comment: @Tsyvarev. It works as expected.
Thank you so much for saving my time.